# How to deserialise a JSON where the corresponding Haskell type is available during runtime as a value?

Tags: haskell, reify, rank-n-types

I'm trying to implement a port of DelayedJob (from the Rails world) in Haskell.

Here's the typeclass I have which represents a `DelayedJob`

```
class (FromJSON j, ToJSON j, FromJSON r, ToJSON r) => DelayedJob j r | j -> r where
  serialise :: j -> Value
  serialise = toJSON

  deserialise :: Value -> Either String j
  deserialise = parseEither parseJSON

  runJob :: j -> AppM r
```

Here's how I plan to use it:

```
createJob :: (DelayedJob j r) => j -> AppM JobId
```

I'm getting stuck with writing a fairly general `invokeJob` function which will read a row from the `jobs` table, look at the `jobs.jobtype` column and invoke the correct version of the `runJob` version (i.e. the `runJob` function belonging to the correct type-class instance).

I have the following, but it is full of boilerplate:

```
data JobType = SyncContacts | SendEmail | SendSms deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

invokeJob :: JobId -> AppM ()
invokeJob jid = do
  job <- fetchJob jid
  case (job ^. jobtype) of
     SyncContacts -> case (deserialise (job ^. jobdata) :: Either String SynContactsJob) of
       Left e -> error e
       Right j -> storeJobResult jid $ runAppM j
     SendEmail -> case (deserialise (job ^. jobdata) :: Either String SendEmailJob) of
       Left e -> error e
       Right j -> storeJobResult jid $ runAppM j
     SendSms -> case (deserialise (job ^. jobdata) :: Either String SendSms) of
       Left e -> error e
       Right j -> storeJobResult jid $ runAppM j
```

Essentially, is there a way to constrain the concrete type of the `deserialise` function dynamically during runtime without having to write so much boilerplate?

Comment: Not answering your question, but the `serialize` and `deserialize` functions should not be defined, as it seems they only can have a single implementation, that is derived from the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if something like this could work. I don't know the framework you are working with.

```
let go :: forall jobtype . Job -> JobID -> ....
    go job jid =
       case deserialise (job ^. jobdata) :: Either String jobtype of
          Left e -> error e
          Right j -> storeJobResult jid $ runAppM j
case (job ^. jobtype) of
     SyncContacts -> go @ SynContactsJob job jid
     SendEmail    -> go @ SendEmail job jid
     ...
```

Otherwise, I'd try to see if singletons can help. Proxies could also be used if you don't want to enable ambiguous types & type applications.

Comment: Not sure that's the kind of boilerplate removal I'm looking at. I'm trying to take the approach outlined at https://gist.github.com/aaronlevin/4aa22bd9c79997029167 - Any help with that?

Answer (score 1):

I am loath to suggest it, but IMHO the "right" thing to do here is to forego type safety with a little runtime polymorphism. Instead of a type class, have an opaque `Handler` of sorts, in your case it'd probably be something like `Value -> AppM ()`.

Just put these in a `Map Type Handler` or something along those lines, which you can update dynamically; whereby `Type` is what you use to distinguish your job types (i.e. some sum type or, for minimum type safety, just a `String`). When you pull out a job you can just look up the appropriate handler in the list; The handler is opaque and knows which types it is responsible for, so the user end doesn't need to know how to deserialize values.

This isn't very clever but should work nevertheless.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, my best ideas so far, as well. I'm looking for something better than this :)